# need to get the images from docker to run in kubernetes error certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, docker-machine

am trying to run a kubernetes cluster in my local machine.I have Installed kubectl,docker toolbox,minikube and virtual box .

Before docker build:

```
minikube docker env
```

Did a docker build and am trying to push the docker image in local registry:
    docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2

after which am trying to push the image to local repo

```
docker tag d3ecb4966f24 X.X.X.X:2376/image
docker push X.X.X.X:2376/image
```

Error : x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got two options:

1. Bring the registry up with a valid certificate (recommended for production)
2. Add your registry as insecure in your docker daemons (not recommended for production) :

**Dont do this in production, make it secure**

Add the following to daemon.json

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["X.X.X.X:2376"]
}
```

Restart docker daemon

Comment: couldn't find the daemon.json in my machine,Is it a different file when we are running docker toolbox with minikube in virtual box.

Comment: Dont know about the docker toolbox but if you are on linux you should create the file in /etc/docker/daemon.json then paste contents and save and restart the service